# Galaxy Gear not locking Note 3

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-3, samsung-galaxy-gear

Device: Samsung Galaxy Gear paired with Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

I am receiving notifications on the Gear from the Note, so I know it is connected.

I have turned Auto Lock on. When I did this, it asked me for a new unlock pattern and backup PIN, which I gave. Now, when I hold the Note 3, it has reverted to just "swipe to unlock". However, when put the watch down on the table and walk away (5 metres, ten meters), the Note 3 doesn't lock.

Below is a Screen shot from Note 3 showing: Gear Manager > Settings > Auto lock turned on.

[image: Screen shot from Note 3 showing: Gear Manager > Settings > Auto lock turned on]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: OK, this is what I have found so far.

It isn't locking exactly i.e. when the watch is out of range, it doesn't automatically lock the phone - if the screen was active, it stays active until it times out normally. But when I try to open the device, I need to use the secure method to open the device. And when I bring the watch back into range, I can just swipe to open it.

Is my expectation off here? I thought it would lock the device when I go out of range.